# Can xdotool work after my screen becomes locked?

Tags: firefox, ubuntu, xdotool

On Ubuntu 14.04, I want to use xdotools to simulate mouses and keys  on a firefox window. I want to do that when  I am away, so I also like to lock my window. Is it possible for xdotool still to work on a firefox window after I lock my screen? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not, but when i need to do gnome background tasks and kinda lock my pc I do `ctrl+alt+F1`, this makes your screen to go on tty1 and showing text-mode login.

 to get back to gnome use `ctrl+alt+F7`